# Anchor tags in nav bar on the website are not working properly. [HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css

I have a issue with anchor tags in the nav bar on my website. Here is the video > https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M7sbA8bdrTyd3YJIsmgUWyBUaJXM1wEr/view

Result should be different though. There should be a underline bar/line when anchor tag is hovered. And button should do the transition effect when hovered. As well pointer is missing on both. I think that issue is padding and / or margin. I had to insert css3 as a snippet, as the code sample wont register it. Code is not showing proper result as i have plenty of files on the machine. (Normalize, Bootstrap, Main pictures, fonts etc.)
Here is my code :

** CSS3 **

```css
/* --- BUTTON SIGN --- */
.but:link,
.but:visited,
input[type=submit] {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}
.btn-sign:link,
.btn-sign:visited {
    border: 1px solid #3498db;
    color: #3498db;
}

.but:hover,
.but:active,
input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=submit]:active {
    background-color: #3498db;
}
.btn-sign:hover,
.btn-sign:active {
    border: 1px solid #3498db;
    color: #fff;
}

/* SIGN UP BUTTON */
#btnsu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 85%;
    top: 6%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* HEADER */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */

header {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7))), url(Images/bh1.jpg);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(Images/bh1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logo {
    height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 65px;
}

.logo-black {
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

/* Main Nav */
.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 40%;
}

.main-nav li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-top: 13.8%;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 8px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3498db;
}

/* Mobile Nav */
.mobile-nav-icon {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.icon-mob {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!-- HEADER STARTS -->
    <header>
         <nav>
            <div class="row">
                <img id="logo1" src="resources/images/nexcliclogo2.png" alt="nexclic-logo" class="logo">
                    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                        <li><a class="navl" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="navl" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a class="navl" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <a id="btnsu" href="#signup" class="but btn-sign">Sign Up</a>
                </ul>
                    <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="icon ion-ios-menu icon-mob"></i></a>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="hero-text-box">
                <h1 id="headerh1">Rise Up With Us</h1>
                <a id="btnsm" class="btn btn-ghost js--scroll-to-start" href="#">Show me more</a>
            </div>
    </header>
    <!-- HEADER ENDS -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the CSS which you posted in the comments is that `h1` overlaps navigation. This problem itself comes from a huge amount of "dirty hacking" in your CSS. So, I completely rewrited the code from scratch, and here it is:

(Note that HTML code was also rewrited).

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <img id="logo1" src="resources/images/nexcliclogo2.png" alt="nexclic-logo" class="logo">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                <li><a class="navl" href="#home">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="navl" href="#about">Products</a></li>
                <li><a class="navl" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <a id="btnsu" href="#signup" class="but btn-sign">Sign Up</a>
            </ul>
            <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="icon ion-ios-menu icon-mob"></i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="hero-text-box">
    <div>
        <h1 id="headerh1">Rise Up With Us</h1>
        <p><a id="btnsm" class="btn btn-ghost js--scroll-to-start" href="#">Show me more</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.hero-text-box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.hero-text-box div {
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    margin: 0; /* Overwriting browser defaults */
}

header {
    position: absolute;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100vw;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 0;  /* Overwriting browser defaults */
    margin-top: 0;    /* Overwriting browser defaults */
    margin-bottom: 0; /* Overwriting browser defaults */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    /* Try to resize your browser screen to 500px in width or smaller */
    nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none; /* Overwriting browser defaults */
}

nav ul li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 1rem;
}


nav { margin-top: 1rem; }
#logo1 { margin-left: 1rem; }
nav ul { margin-right: 1rem; }
</style>
```

Comment: @AndreasDEV By the way, your code (without any changes) works for me. It works here at Stack Overflow (when you press "Run code snippet" button) and it works for me at jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqany7om/ . Probably it was overwritten by some another CSS rules (which you have not posted here)?

Comment: Hm i see. Ill check that out now. But i believe there is no overwriting at all.

Comment: @AndreasDEV You could post entire CSS in another jsFilddle, I will look it

Comment: @AndreasDEV See updated answer. And don't forgot upvote (click the upper triangle) and accept it (click the check mark)! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will test it out now. 
Meanwhile, could you explain it, what does "dirty hacking" means? As well ,what was the exact problem with the h1 overwriting?
One more thing, why did you split the hero-text-box and header? Shouldn't the content be in the header all together?

Cheers!

Comment: @AndreasDEV Also, I added media querie for narrow screens (500px) just now, so see this update too.

Comment: @AndreasDEV Here is your "dirty hacking": https://jsfiddle.net/zs2g1hmy/ . That's mean that instead of clean modern logic it was a mix of outdated tricks (`top: 50%`) and mispractices (`width: 1140;`). As as a result, the code becomes hard to understand and hard to maintain.

Comment: @AndreasDEV I divided them because it was the most fast way to implement the correct logic. You could fix the HTML back again, but obviously it will be necessary to add the same changes in the CSS.

Comment: @AndreasDEV And here is the problem with overlapping: https://imgur.com/a/it8FCZN

Comment: Wow. Thanks for all of the info! I know its not responsive yet, i am working on media queries at the end. But thanks for the reminder! 
Helped a lot! Fixed up everything!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way

or [this link](https://codepen.io/ankit567/pen/ajLMqv)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- HEADER STARTS -->
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="row text-flex">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <img id="logo1" src="https://attachedlanguage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/dummy-logo.png" alt="nexclic-logo" class="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                        <li><a class="navl" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="navl" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a class="navl" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <a id="btnsu" href="#signup" class="but btn-sign">Sign Up</a>
                    </ul>
                    <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="icon ion-ios-menu icon-mob"></i></a>
                </div>
             </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="hero-text-box">
            <h1 id="headerh1">Rise Up With Us</h1>
            <hr class="heading-hr">
            <a id="btnsm" class="btn btn-ghost js--scroll-to-start" href="#">Show me more</a>
        </div>
        </header>
        <!-- HEADER ENDS -->



/* --- BUTTON SIGN --- */
.but:link,
.but:visited,
input[type=submit] {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}
.btn-sign:link,
.btn-sign:visited {
    border: 1px solid #3498db;
    color: #3498db;
}

.but:hover,
.but:active,
input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=submit]:active {
    background-color: #3498db;
}
.btn-sign:hover,
.btn-sign:active {
    border: 1px solid #3498db;
    color: #fff;
}
nav {
    max-width: 85%;
    margin: auto;
} 
/* SIGN UP BUTTON */

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* HEADER */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- */

header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url(Images/bh1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background: #262626;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

 .hero-text-box {
   text-align: center;
    color: #fff; 
} 
#headerh1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 80px;
}
.heading-hr {
    border: none;
    height: 3px;
    width: 8%;
    background: #3498db;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.row.text-flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo-black {
    display: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

/* Main Nav */
.main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}
.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn-ghost {
    border: 1px solid #3498db;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color: #3498db;
}
.btn-ghost:hover {
    background: #3498db;
    color: #fff;
}
.main-nav li a:link, .main-nav li a:visited  {
    margin: 0px 50px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}
.main-nav li a:hover, .main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3498db;
}

/* Mobile Nav */
.mobile-nav-icon {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.icon-mob {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #fff;
}
```